# I need to reverse an IP address but am unclear how to use IPy ).reverseNames()

Tags: python

Here is the script.  I have been attempting to modify the print line ( in bold ).

reverseNames() is from the IPy module.  I am unclear how to implement in this example.

print addy.reverseNames()  % (addy)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import re

try:
    if sys.argv[1:]:
        print "File: %s" % (sys.argv[1])
        logfile = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        logfile = raw_input("Please enter a log file to parse, e.g /var/log/secure: ")
    try:
        file = open(logfile, "r")
        ips = []
        for text in file.readlines():
           text = text.rstrip()
           regex = re.findall(r'(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})$',text)
           if regex is not None and regex not in ips:
               ips.append(regex)

        for ip in ips:
           outfile = open("/tmp/blocked_ips_test", "a")
           addy = "".join(ip)
           if addy is not '':
              **print "IP: %s" % (addy)**
              outfile.write(addy)
              outfile.write("\n")
    finally:
        file.close()
        outfile.close()
except IOError, (errno, strerror):
        print "I/O Error(%s) : %s" % (errno, strerror)
```

Comment: What happens when you run this on your `logfile`? How would you like to modify your print output?

Comment: This is the current output:               IP: 10.102.36.38
IP: 192.168.100.11
IP: 192.168.100.12                   The desired output is this:           ip.reverseNames()
    ['0.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa.', '1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa.', '2.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa.',                      These come from the localhost IP addresses 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2 etc..     The function reverseNames converts the IP to a DNS reverse zone configuration.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm unclear as to what you'd like it to print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already capture the individual octets as a list of strings, just reverse the list and join on a dot.  If you want the `.in-addr.arpa.` suffix tacked on, that should be trivial.

```
addy = '.'.join(reversed(ip)) + ".in-addr.arpa.'
```

If you do wish to use the [IPy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/IPy/) API, you need to convert the string representation to an IPy object first.

```
import IPy
i = IP('.'.join(ip))
addy = i.reverseNames()
```

Comment: >>> addy = '.'.join(reversed('127.0.0.1'))
>>> addy
'1...0...0...7.2.1'
expected result of a reverse-octet format is 1.0.0.127 so even without the extra dots it is still wrong

Comment: @Stoff looks like your input is different than the OP's, or perhaps I originally misread their code. The expected input `ip` should be a list like `['127', '0', '0', '1']` whereas your result looks like you have passed in the bare string `'127.0.0.1'`

Answer (score 4):

The ipaddress module in Python standard library also supports IPv6.

```
from ipaddress import ip_address

print(ip_address("127.0.0.1").reverse_pointer)
print(ip_address("2a03:2880:f10a:83:face:b00c::25de").reverse_pointer)
```

```
1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa
e.d.5.2.0.0.0.0.c.0.0.b.e.c.a.f.3.8.0.0.a.0.1.f.0.8.8.2.3.0.a.2.ip6.arpa
```

Comment: best "working" answer. the accepted answer is not a working solution for the reverse-octet format

Comment: I agree that this would be the way to go for Python 3.3+. When the question was originally asked I guess they were still using Python 2 which did not have this module. The bare `print`s without parentheses in the question suggest this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want you can take Occupy libraries IPY .

```
import IPy
i = IP('.'.join(ip))
addy = i.reverseNames()
```

This can help you install the library
https://github.com/autocracy/python-ipy/wiki

on the contrary

```
addy = ".".join(reversed(ip.split('.'))) +'.in-addr.arpa'
```

Comment: this is the correct answer, but not the best solution which is @L. Kärkkäinen